# Why does the traceback print earlier than print url?

Tags: python, traceback

As I know when running the following code, the `print(url, end='')` will first print a line.

Then `requests.get(url)` raise an exception, which triggers the `traceback.print_exc()`.

But in my test, the `traceback.print_exc()` print on the screen earlier than `print(url, end='')`.

Why?

On the other hand if I replace the `traceback.print_exc()` with `print('error occurred')`, it works as what I thought.

Seems that the `traceback.print_exc()` has a higher priority?

```py
import traceback

import requests


url = 'http://www.szwb.gov.cn/wap/jggk/gzdt/201809/t20180919_14099889.htm'

try:
    print(url, end='')
    response = requests.get(url)
    # balabala
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
    # print('error occurred.')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print` will output to STDOUT and `traceback.print_exc()` will output to STDERR. STDOUT is "buffered" and STDERR is not. From [this article](https://eulertech.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/sys-out-flush-in-python/):

> By default, I/O in programs is buffered which means the IO is not served immediately byte by byte rather are served from a temporary storage to the requesting program... By buffering, the whole block is read into the buffer at once then the individual bytes are delivered to you from the (fast in-memory) buffer area.

When the buffer is "flushed", it will be displayed. Normally, if the output is a terminal, the buffer is flushed at a new line.

In Python 3, you can force this with the `flush` kwarg:

```py
print(url, end='', flush=True)
```

Which is effectively the same as:

```py
import sys

# ...

print(url, end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `end` kwarg:

```py
print(url)
```

Note that this will print a newline after the URL. This could be undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

For the I/Os to the Console is usually buffered in python. And the I/Os which is sending an error report has a higher priority to a function call of print.

That is, 
`print(url, end='')`puts its data into the buffer firstly. Then the error report put its data into the buffer.

When the error report puts its data, the data of the print function is still in the buffer and has a lower priority. So the error report puts its data ahead of it and it shows before it.

Comment: Is there a source for this?

Comment: Please check [python.sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html). Print calls `sys.stdout` and `traceback.print_exc()` calls `sys.stderr`. When interactive, stdout and stderr streams are line-buffered. Which has the higher priority is not defined. But to most realizations, stderr does.

Comment: Pretty interesting, thanks! Seems like Python 2 differs a fair bit from Python 3 in this respect.