# Why does error message in Python is displayed earlier than the print method

Tags: python, mongodb, printing, flush

I have visited a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265549/why-does-the-traceback-print-earlier-than-print-url) in SO which was asked earlier.
In the answer its mentioned that :

> When the buffer is "flushed", it will be displayed. Normally, if the
> output is a terminal, the buffer is flushed at a new line.

In the below code I have set `flush` is `True` in `print` statement but still the `error` message is displayed earlier.

Below is a simple program which performs `CRUD` operations in `mongoDB` database.

### Code:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1/27017")

mydb = client["Employee"]

collection = mydb.collection

# record = {"firstname":"Udesh", "lastname":"Ranjan"}

# collection.insert_one(record)

records = [{"Name":"Your Name", "age":78, "Passion":"Astronomy"},
           {"Name":"Your Name", "age":38, "Passion":"Basket Ball"}]

# collection.insert_many(records)

print(collection.find_one(), flush=True) // flushing the output stream
print(dir(collection), flush=True)
# print(collection.find())
condition = {}
# condition = {"age":{"$in":[35, 35, 78, 22]}}
# condition = {"age":{"$lt":100, "$gt":30}}
# condition = {"age":{"$lt":100, "$gt":10}, "Name":"Your Name"}
condition = {"$or":[{"Name":"Your Name"}, {"firstname":"Udesh"}]}

for data in collection.find(condition):
    # print(data, type(data))
    for index, (key, item) in enumerate(data.items()):
        if index != 0:
            print(key, item, flush=True)
    print()


inventory = mydb.inventory
records = [
    {"item":"journal", "qty":30, "size":{"h":14, "w":20, "uom":"cm"}, "price":450.00},
    {"item":"journal", "qty":20, "size":{"h":14, "w":25, "uom":"cm"}, "price":350.00},
    {"item":"journal", "qty":10, "size":{"h":14, "w":10, "uom":"cm"}, "price":550.00},
    {"item":"journal", "qty":3, "size": {"h":14, "w":30, "uom":"cm"}, "price":250.00},
    {"item":"journal", "qty":50, "size":{"h":14, "w":50, "uom":"cm"}, "price":150.00},
    {"item":"journal", "qty":39, "size":{"h":0.4, "w":.30, "uom":"m"}, "price":5000.00},
    {"item":"journal", "qty":25, "size":{"h":140, "w":100, "uom":"mm"}, "price":1453.00},
]

records = []
inventory.insert_many(records)

condition = {}

for record in inventory.find(condition):
    print(record)
```

### Output:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\python.exe C:\Users\devpa\PycharmProjects\MondoDBKrishNaik\src\hello.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\devpa\PycharmProjects\MondoDBKrishNaik\src\hello.py", line 47, in <module>
    inventory.insert_many(records)
  File "C:\Users\devpa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\devpa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 698, in insert_many
    raise TypeError("documents must be a non-empty list")
TypeError: documents must be a non-empty list
{'_id': ObjectId('63ad6d71597ce7bc64ed82e0'), 'firstname': 'Udesh', 'lastname': 'Ranjan'}
['_BaseObject__codec_options', '_BaseObject__read_concern', '_BaseObject__read_preference', '_BaseObject__write_concern', '_Collection__create', '_Collection__create_indexes', '_Collection__database', '_Collection__find_and_modify', '_Collection__full_name', '_Collection__name', '_Collection__write_response_codec_options', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__next__', '__orig_bases__', '__parameters__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_aggregate', '_aggregate_one_result', '_command', '_count_cmd', '_delete', '_delete_retryable', '_insert_one', '_is_protocol', '_read_preference_for', '_retryable_non_cursor_read', '_socket_for_reads', '_socket_for_writes', '_timeout', '_update', '_update_retryable', '_write_concern_for', '_write_concern_for_cmd', 'aggregate', 'aggregate_raw_batches', 'bulk_write', 'codec_options', 'count_documents', 'create_index', 'create_indexes', 'database', 'delete_many', 'delete_one', 'distinct', 'drop', 'drop_index', 'drop_indexes', 'estimated_document_count', 'find', 'find_one', 'find_one_and_delete', 'find_one_and_replace', 'find_one_and_update', 'find_raw_batches', 'full_name', 'index_information', 'insert_many', 'insert_one', 'list_indexes', 'name', 'next', 'options', 'read_concern', 'read_preference', 'rename', 'replace_one', 'update_many', 'update_one', 'watch', 'with_options', 'write_concern']
firstname Udesh
lastname Ranjan

firstname Udesh
lastname Ranjan

Name Your Name
age 78
Passion Astronomy

Name Your Name
age 38
Passion Basket Ball


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error message is displayed due to the records are empty.

But why the `error` message is displayed before the `print` statement even after `flushing` the `output stream`?

Answer (score 2):

Because you call `inventory.insert_many` with an explicitly empty `records`. You literally have

```
records = []
inventory.insert_many(records)
```

Remove the line

```
records = []
```

and then the line `inventory.insert_many(records)` won't give you your error.

Comment: Thanks Elliott but I have done it purposefully to see what happens and its generating error. My question is why `error` message is displayed earlier even after `flushing` the `output stream`. The `print` messages should be displayed earlier isn't it?

Comment: @devp Because there are newlines in the stacktrace and newlines trigger buffer flushing. Also note that is output to stderr (not stdout).

Comment: But I am flushing the output and by default the `print` method display a `newline` @ the end of line so `stdout` messages should be displayed earlier than `stderr`

Comment: @devp But the error happens first, and you don't catch the exception so the stacktrace is printed. And the stacktrace contains newlines; and newlines flush. So it prints immediately. I'm not sure why you would *want* to see an error at some other time. Either handle the error (with a try except), or prevent it by checking for an empty list. I don't think anyone *wants* a programming language that silently swallows errors.

Comment: But there are `newlines` generate using `print()` before the `error` message generated due to `inventory.insert_many(records)`. I'm not trying to display `error` @ some time. I still cannot understand why the `error` stack trace message is display before the `print statement` message even after flushing the `stream`.

Comment: When this line executes (`inventory.insert_many(records)`) it raises an error. When an error is raised, it prints the stack trace. Printing the stack trace happens when the error is raised. Simple as that. Your prints after that are irrelevant. The stack trace has already printed.

Comment: I ran the program few more times and I noticed that this time the `error` `stack trace` was generated at bottom. The `stack trace` was @ bottom. Why then the `error` message is being displayed at different places some time @ very beginning and some time @ very bottom its like unpredictable where the message will be displayed we can't tell?